# Knockout Mapping a foreach with another collection than the source

Tags: knockout.js

I need to translate a text.

This is my array of languages

```
[
   {iso:"fr",name:"French"},
   {iso:"en",name:"English"},
   {iso:"de",name:"German"},
]
```

My model

```
{
   translation :
   [
      {iso:"fr",content:"Bonjour"},
      {iso:"en",content:"Hello"}
   ]
}
```

I'd like to have a form with all the languages displayed and my mapping would fill my translation model.

Do you have any idea how I can do that with knockout ? Or any way to get near that ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve but I guess you want to change the translation based on the language that was chosen.

You could make the languages an observable array.
Make the selected language an observable property.
Make the translation a computed property which returns the desired translation based on the SelectedLanguageProperty.

Take a look at this example : http://jsfiddle.net/dtiemstra/gejde/2/

Comment: That's not quite what I want. I want a form that display an input foreach languages and my mapping would return only the filled languages with the content and only the iso code of the language. Is that clear enough ?